# How can one be born as a Daitya, Danava, or Naga?

Tags: naga, daitya

The Yajnas in the Vedas provide the means to attain heaven (swarga, gandharva loka), etc that are situated above earth. These yajnas also allow one to be born as a god. For example, doing 100 Ashwamedha yajnas gives the fruit of becoming an Indra. The Upanishads also describe meditations one can do to be born as gods. The Madhu vidya for example allows one to be born as a Vasu. These heavenly realms are realms of paradise and material enjoyment, and the inhabitants stay there for a very long time, thousands of years or so.

However, below the Earth are situated seven subterranean realms. These are inhabited by Daityas, Danavas, and Nagas who enjoy tremendous material opulence. The Bhagavata Purana calls these realms "bila-swargas", or subterranean realms. Narada Rishi himself even said that Patala is better than swarga in the [Vishnu Purana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp063.htm#page_204) and Mahabharata:

> The Muni Nárada, after his return from those regions to the skies, declared amongst the celestials that Pátála was much more delightful than Indra's heaven. "What," exclaimed the sage, "can be compared to Pátála, where the Nágas are decorated with brilliant and beautiful and pleasure-shedding jewels? who will not delight in Pátála, where the lovely daughters of the Daityas and Dánavas wander about, fascinating even the most austere; where the rays of the sun diffuse light, and not heat, by day; and where the moon shines by night for illumination, not for cold; where the sons of Danu, happy in the enjoyment of delicious viands and strong wines, know not how time passes? There are beautiful groves and streams and lakes where the lotus blows; and the skies are resonant with the Koïl's song. Splendid ornaments, fragrant perfumes, rich unguents, the blended music of the lute and pipe and tabor; these and many other enjoyments are the common portion of the Dánavas, Daityas, and snake-gods, who inhabit the regions of Pátála."

My question is, how can one be born in the Patalas as a Daitya, Danava, or Naga?

Answer (score 4):

Krishna says in *Uddhava Gita* 17.51 (Swami Madhavananda translator):

> Swayed by his past works, a man through his attachment to Sattva becomes a sage or a god, under the influence of Rajas an Asura or man, and under the influence of Tamas a ghost or a beast.

and in *Gita* 9.25 Sri Krishna says (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> Those who worship the gods go to the gods, those who worship the manes go to the manes, those who worship the spirits go to the spirits, and those who worship Me come to Me.

and the *Astavakra Samhita* 1.11 says (Swami Nityaswarupananda translator):

> He who considers himself free is free indeed, and he who considers himself bound remains bound. "As one thinks, so one becomes' is a popular saying in this world, and it is quite true.

If you think you want to be a Daitya, Danava, or Naga, then think of them.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find verse 17.51 here: https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/ Do you know where it is there?

Comment: in the recension you refer to, similar verses start at verse 10.23

Comment: Yep. Fully agree, well said @SwamiVishwananda  Thx for posting this answer, very helpful 